# How to append different react components to a list on a click of a button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two kinds of components, I want them to appear in the screen on the click of a button, but it is not like show and hide components, it is more like generate theme many times. like if I click the button, I can add more and more, so if i click on the first button it generates component 1 and when I click on the second button it appends the second component to the list and etc.

I have no idea how to achieve this, I thought of storing the components in a state and do a map loop, but i not sure if this possible (storing components in state) and if it's a good practice.

Comment: What you would store in the state is the data that determines which components are created, not the components themselves.

Comment: There is no any data, the component is complex, and made of many components. It is not like if it were a div with some data.

Comment: But the component is dependent on some data, yes? Otherwise they would all look identical.

Comment: If they are all identical then what you store in the state is how many component there are - just an integer.

Comment: yes, but the structure of the components is different. and the very basic elements they are made of are different., for example, components made of div and different `input`, and another one made of `div` and `select` element.

Comment: So your state could look like ["input", "input", "select", "input"] and your render function reads this array and generate the correct components accordingly.

Comment: Could you write a simple code for illustration, as an answer, using function component?

Comment: Yes but probably not tonight, sorry

Comment: Anyway, I got the idea, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have had a similar situation while making a math solving website where I wanted to show the solution (JSX Element) when the user clicks on "solve" button. I don't know if this is the best practice but I just created a `SolutionObject` with the following typescript interface:

```js
interface SolutionObject {
  isSolved: boolean;
  solutionElement: JSX.Element;
}
```

I then initialised the solution object using the `useState()` hook:

```js
const [Solution, solved] = useState<SolutionObject>();
```

Then I used it in my React component like this

```
<div className="solution">
    {Solution?.solutionElement}
</div>
{Solution?.isSolved ? <button onClick={closeBtn}>Close</button> : null}
```

To update the solution, I just updated the solution object with the JSX in `solutionElement` property in a solve function with the correct JSX for step-by-step solution. Here is an example:

```
solved({
      isSolved: true,
      solutionElement:
        // prettier-ignore
        <div className="card">
          <h2>Using Distance Formula</h2>
          <p>
            <Latex>{`$Distance\\ (D) = \\sqrt{(x_{2}-x_{1})^2 + (y_{2}-y_{1})^2}$`}</Latex>
            <br /><br />
            <Latex>{`$D = \\sqrt{(${X2}-${X1})^2 + (${Y2}-${Y1})^2}$`}</Latex>
            <br /><br />
            <Latex>{`$D = \\sqrt{(${X2 - X1})^2 + (${Y2 - Y1})^2}$`}</Latex>
            <br /><br />
            <Latex>{`$D = \\sqrt{${(X2 - X1) ** 2} + ${(Y2 - Y1) ** 2}}$`}</Latex>
            <br /><br />
            <Latex>{`$D = \\sqrt{${(X2 - X1) ** 2 + (Y2 - Y1) ** 2}}$`}</Latex>
            <br /><br />
            <Latex>{`$D = ${formatSquareRoot((X2 - X1) ** 2 + (Y2 - Y1) ** 2).outer}\\sqrt{${formatSquareRoot((X2 - X1) ** 2 + (Y2 - Y1) ** 2).inner}}$`}</Latex>
          </p>
        </div>,
    });
```

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for, but your question sounds similar. I guess you can use this idea to store JSX elements in a state and render them in your component. If you have a list of JSX elements, you may use the `JSX.Element[]` type for them (if you use typescript) and map them

```
{items &&
    items.map((Item, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
            <Item />
        </div>
     ))}
```

Again, I am not much experienced with this and don't know if it is the best practice but it sure works.